# ERLANG: Spawning funs. Different behaviour

Tags: erlang, spawn

Why is the difference between two spawning methods listed below?

```
1> G = fun(X) -> io:format("~p ", [X]) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.44.97283095>
2> [spawn(fun() -> G(X) end) || X <- [1, 2, 3] ]. 
1 2 3 [<0.82.0>,<0.83.0>,<0.84.0>]
3> [spawn(fun() -> fun(X) -> io:format("~p ", [X]) end end) || X <- [1, 2, 3] ].
[<0.86.0>,<0.87.0>,<0.88.0>]
4>
```

Answer (score 6):

In the last example, here is the function being spawned:

```
fun() ->
    fun(X) -> io:format("~p ", [X]) end
end
```

It doesn't actually do anything - it creates an anonymous function but doesn't call it.

To call the function, you'd do something like this:

```
fun() ->
    TheFunction = fun(Y) -> io:format("~p ", [Y]) end,
    TheFunction(X)
end
```

(I changed the argument name from `X` to `Y` for clarity. It doesn't really matter, as function arguments overshadow variables from an outer scope.)

Or to fit it back in the one-liner:

```
4> [spawn(fun() -> TheFunction = fun(Y) -> io:format("~p ", [Y]) end, TheFunction(X) end) || X <- [1, 2, 3] ].
1 2 3 [<0.94.0>,<0.95.0>,<0.96.0>]
```

Now it behaves the same as the other example.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you!
It's clear enough.
The anonymous function have to be named to be called. For example,  if we pass anonymous function as a parameter to another function, it only can be called as a named argument inside wrapping function.